# Flutter / Dart Avoid Using Unnecessary Statements

Tags: flutter, dart

Any idea how I could rewrite this to avoid uneccsary statements?

```
onPressed: () {
   _loggingin == false ? null : validateForm();
}),
```

Comment: What do you actually want your code to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an if statement instead of a ternary operator.

```
onPressed: () {
    if(_loggingin) validateForm();
}),
```

Answer (score 3):

actually you can omit `_loggingin == false` condition, also you can get rid of `() =>` and send `validateForm` as a function delegate.

```
onPressed: () => _loggingin ? validateForm() : null,
```

Comment: This would check _loggingin while the callback is being set up, not a possibly different value when the callback is triggered.  Might not possibly be different, but might be different. :)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz you are completely right, thank you. I will update the answer.